# How do I get the HttpServletRequest in Spring MVC?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

How do I get the HttpServletRequest in Spring MVC?

When trying to get the HttpServletRequest, I get an exception.

**Message** **`No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.`**

Please tell me how to solve the problem?

```
    @Component
    public class AuthenticationSuccessEventListener implements ApplicationListener<AuthenticationSuccessEvent> {


        @Autowired
        private HttpServletRequest request;


        @Override
        public void onApplicationEvent(AuthenticationSuccessEvent a) {
            
            System.out.println(request.getRemoteAddr());
            
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this

```
RequestAttributes reqAtt = RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes();
if (RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes() != null) {
    HttpServletRequest req = ((ServletRequestAttributes) reqAtt).getRequest();
    return req.getRemoteAddr();
}
```

also u need to add/register a RequestContextListener listener in web.xml file.

```
<web-app ...>
   <listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener
    </listener-class>
   </listener>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 0):

> You shouldn't autowire a HttpServletRequest in your aspect as this
> will tie your aspect to be only runnable for classes that are called
> from within an executing HttpServletRequest.
>
> Instead use the RequestContextHolder to get the request when you need
> one.
>
> ```
> private String getRemoteAddress() {
>     RequestAttributes attribs = RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes();
>     if (attribs instanceof NativeWebRequest) {
>         HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) ((NativeWebRequest) attribs).getNativeRequest();
>         return request.getRemoteAddr();
>     }
>     return null;
> }
> ```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/24029989/11985558